# How to group by values from another table in Propel

Tags: php, propel

I have two tables. One table has category field and some aggregated data from data warehouse. And second table has custom_category which can be created in application by grouping categories. On example:

Custom category id 1:

1,2,7,33, 120, ... (category_id)

Custom category id 2:

5,6,9,11,12,13,14...

....

And I need to show statistics for these custom_categories so I need to get data from one table grouped by values from another. How to achieve it using propel?

Probably some of you will suggest to create different model where there is a table with aggregated data for custom_category. But it can't be done! Creating a table with aggregated data from warehouse takes at least an hour. And creating custom categorries and showing stats for them should be done life in application.

Answer (score 0):

What you want here is the `use` functionality.  Assuming you have set up a proper relationship between those tables in your schema:

```
table1Query::create()
    ->joinWithTable2()
    ->useTable2Query()
        ->groupByTable2Column()
    ->endUse()
```

Apologies if I misunderstood the question